# How to use memcached with cakephp native pagination methods?

Tags: cakephp, pagination, memcached

I have been using memcache in my project without any problem.
it works great in find() based queries and custom queries.

But how can I use paginated results with memcache?
I have following block of code i am trying to put in memcache:

`$this->paginate = array('order'=>'order_by ASC','limit' => 1000);
$this->Category->recursive = 2;
$Categories = $this->paginate('Category',array('id'=>5));`

Even if I put variable $Categories in cache, it doesn't work.
any idea, please help.

Thanks a lot in advance.
Vikas

Comment: why cache pagination. what happens when they sort by another field or in different orders? 10 fields with just 20 rows over 2 pages would give 2 X 2 X 10 versions of cache (if ive not missed a few different ways)

Comment: i need caching for better page load speed. it's fetching thousands of records on every page and spending a lot of time in loading.

Comment: @dogmatic69, i am not using sorting, (its hard coded) so its not a problem.

Comment: 1000's of records on each page load? if you are indexing and optimising queries there should be no problem. anyhow caching works just the same

Answer (score 0):

```
$tmp = sha1($this->params['url']['url']);
    $something = Cache::read('something_'.$tmp);
    if(!$something){
    $something = $this->paginate();
    }
    Cache::write($something, 'something_'.$tmp);

    $this->set(compact('something'));
```

Comment: you could use _<page_number> but i cant remeber off hand where it is and to lazy to find it :D

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i already tried using page URL and page number to set cache. but it causes another trouble. if $this->paginate(); is not called inside controller (because its in the condition), the paginate helpers in view files won't work. the only way i see here is to write my own pagination class, and i won't get benefit from cake's ability to fetch all database relations by looking at the model.